# magento 2 "out of stock" not displaying in configurable swatch option product

Tags: magento2.2, out-of-stock, configurable-swatches

In my magnto 2.2 "out of stock" option product was not dispalying in configurable swatch product. I like to list all option even if "out of stock".

Please help to solve this solution.

Comment: This is help me on magento 2.3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/52197253

Comment: Hi @waff, I tried but not working.

Comment: Hi @waff, Yeah got the result, but it not gray out. Thanks for your support